# how python 3 handles big integers internally

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

I was trying to solve a puzzle, which involved finding first Fibonacci number containing `n` digit. 
I wrote this function and was pleasantly surprised to see it it work for very large values of `n` and produces results very fast. What is the secret behind this?

```
def fib_morethan (n):
    '''return first Fibonacci number > n and its index'''
    if n < 0:
        return (1, 0)

    a, b = 0, 1
    counter = 1
    while b <= n:
        a, b, counter = b, a + b, counter + 1
    return counter + 1, b
```

Testing the output

```
%time fib_morethan(10**70)
Wall time: 0 ns
(337, 12004657173391489668678522013941832147005954727556362660159637892443617)

%time fib_morethan(10**999)
Wall time: 1 ms
(4783, 10700...  (990 digits here)   ... 27816)
```

Comment: Seems like I need to improve my **searching** skills before my python skills. Trust me, I tried searching it on google as well as on stackoverflow but could not find it :(

Comment: @coldspeed, can /should I delete my question ?

Comment: That's up to you. Personally, I don't think it's a problem either way.

Comment: Thanks, think I would not delete it, it may help someone who is at my level of searching skills, though I doubt it